# Perform opportunistic disk reads

Tags: c, linux

In Linux, how do I implement a function (or direct system call) that will:

- block until at least some minimum number of bytes (32 or 4,096) are read from an ordinary file (on local disk, not a “file” connected to a network device) and
- provide, when it does return, as many bytes as are currently available (immediately, with no further blocking), up to a passed buffer size (32 MiB)?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to block when reading regular files. You need to write your own loop that keeps reading until it gets what it needs.

Comment: So read in a loop until you have all the data you need (keep track by using variables that you update), `read` returns `0`, or `read` returns with an unrecoverable error.

Comment: Guys... what do you need clarified? I said my question as clearly as I can. I guess I can inform you that `read` will block until the entire buffer is filled but if you didnt know that maybe you shouldnt vote to close

Comment: AFAIK you give `read()` a maximum, not a minimum size to read.

Comment: My best guess as to what you meant to say is “I want to issue a read requests that blocks until at least 32 bytes are available and then returns with all the bytes that are available, up to 32 MiB.” But the question does not say that. If that is what you mean, then update the post to say that. If that is not what you mean, then explain the differences between that and what you mean.

Comment: Are you reading from an actual file, from disk storage (or similar)?  If so, it appears you're misusing a state-based, designed-to-be-static data store as some kind of streaming media source and expecting it to act like one.  A file is not a dynamic stream of flowing data.

Comment: I agree with others saying "you cannot do this in general".  Your code should always be able to handle a short read; there is no way in the Unix API to completely eliminate the possibility.  Now, if short reads are happening so often that they are causing a *measurable* and *significant* performance problem, then I'd say you should look for the *cause* of the short reads (flaky I/O?  timer signal frequency set too high? etc) and address that cause instead of its symptom.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes what you said is what I meant but I'm not sure how my question is different from what you said besides the literal words being different. I also mentioned EAGAIN so people wouldn't think I meant fread however I forgot that nonblocking doesn't appear to work on files so I guess this was mostly a moot question unless there is in fact a way :(

Comment: Based on comments so far, Linux does not provide a way to do exactly what you request, notably because it does not provide non-blocking reads from ordinary files or information about how much data is currently immediately available in operating system buffer. So you can perform the initial blocking read of a desired number of bytes but cannot perform a non-blocking read of whatever additional data is immediately available…

Comment: … However, this is an X-Y problem. The question asks for X, a way to read data if it happens to be available, but the actual goal is Y, to perform useful activity while waiting for disk reads. This can be achieved at least in part by using multiple threads: One to read from disk and one to perform other work. The disk-read thread would perform blocking threads and inform the other thread when data is available (by an atomic counter, by semaphores, or other means as chosen)…

Comment: … This is only a partial solution for the explicitly asked question because it appears the only supported way to read whatever data is immediately available is to perform repeated blocking reads of one byte (or perhaps of the disk block size), so that the disk-read thread has always read as much as is available and reported that to the other thread. To support getting up to 32 MiB, the disk-read thread would have to use an algorithm that performs up to 65,536 reads of 512 bytes each, in order to ensure that whatever lesser amount might be immediately available is made promptly available…

Comment: … to the other thread. That is, there is no “read whatever is available” system call, so the disk-read thread has to find out what is available by reading blocks one at a time, reporting them to the other thread one at a time, and suffering a block when no more data is immediately available…

Comment: … Nonetheless, if the application can benefit from doing other work while disk reads are pending, it is not unlikely something could be designed that performs blocking reads of useful amounts of data (possibly larger than single disk blocks) and makes those available to the other thread.

Answer (score 3):

This is what `read` does:

- If there's no data available, it waits until data is available.
- If/when there's data available, it returns all available data up to the specified amount.

For example, say you want to read at least 4 KiB, and you ask for 64 KiB. If there's 8 KiB available, `read` will immediately return that 8 KiB. (It won't wait for another 56 KiB to arrive.)

Similarly, if only 2 KiB is initially available, `read` will return that. There's no way to tell the system to wait until 4 KiB is available. So that means we need to call `read` if we want to obtain a minimum amount.

```c
ssize_t read_min( int fd, void *buf, size_t max_to_read, size_t min_to_read ) {
   if ( min_to_read > SSIZE_MAX )
      min_to_read = SSIZE_MAX;
   if ( max_to_read > SSIZE_MAX )
      max_to_read = SSIZE_MAX;
      
   size_t total_read = 0;
   while ( total_read < min_to_read ) {
      ssize_t bytes_read = read( fd, buf + total_read, max_to_read );
      if ( bytes_read < 0 )
         return -1;
      if ( bytes_read == 0 )
         return total_read;

      max_to_read -= bytes_read;
      total_read  += bytes_read;
   }

   return total_read;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the amount of reads/system calls I do. 2 reads would be very ok if I knew how to mix blocking and nonblocking on the same fd

Comment: This does the minimum number of system calls. (For a non-blocking handle. It makes no sense to make a handle non-blocking if you want blocking reads.)

Comment: @EricStotch *I'm trying to reduce the amount of reads/system calls I do* Why?  Have you profiled your application and found that too many `read()` calls have become a bottleneck?  You're already doing some sort of IO operation, and the latency of a single one of those will dwarf the overhead of making system calls.

Comment: I meant "For a blocking handle" in my earlier comment.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that makes sense. This code is meant to be a library function. I occasionally had code process data faster than the disk but I can't imagine how likely a system call overhead would matter if disk is slow

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use a blocking call `select()` on file-descriptor.

- We assume file is constantly written in to, like a log-file or a CDR-file.
- When you don't specify `timeout` in `select()` call, it blocks until file descriptor is available for read/write, just for read in our case.
- Using `FD_SET` we set our `fd`, make `select()` wait until it's ready for reading.
- When `select` returns, verify if `fd` indeed ready for reading using `FD_ISSET` macro.
- Repeat the steps until you've read enough data to meet your requirement.

This is a common method used in `sockets` to read expected payload/data after a header/type-value.

```c
// assumes buf_sz > read_min
ssize_t read_min (const int fd, void *buf, size_t buf_sz, size_t read_min) {
    if (buf_sz > SSIZE_MAX) buf_sz = SSIZE_MAX;
    if (read_min > buf_sz) read_min = buf_sz;
    ssize_t total = 0;
    ssize_t bytes_read = 0;

    while (total < read_min) {
        fd_set rfds;
        FD_ZERO (&rfds);
        FD_SET (fd, &rfds);

        int status = select (fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL); // blocking call
        if (-1  == status)
            perror ("read_min-select()");
        if (FD_ISSET (fd, &rfds)) {

            bytes_read = read (fd, buf + total, buf_sz - total);
            if (bytes_read > 0)
                total  += bytes_read;
            if (bytes_read < 0)
                perror ("read_min-read()");
         /* if (0 == bytes_read) // EOF, do you want to return here?
               return total;
          */
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Code should have comments or other documentation explaining it. Code without sufficient information is not a good answer.

Comment: Yes, one *can* do that, but I don't see the point of interposing `select()` in this case.  There's only the one file to read, and nothing else to do but wait (if necessary) for it to be ready, so why not just let the `read()` block as it needs to do, thus avoiding `select()` and all its accoutrements?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function that does what I think you are asking:

- perform a read that blocks until it transfers at least *n* bytes, where *n* > 1, yet
- read up to many times *n* bytes if it can do so without blocking more than it needs to do to get *n* bytes.

You can build your own on top of `read()`, however.  `read()` is a good fit because (with blocking I/O, the default) it does what you want for the case of *n* == 1.  Therefore, if you simply perform `read()`s into the same buffer until you have transferred at least *n* bytes in total, or the end of the file is reached or an error occurs, then the overall result is what you describe.  Something like this:

```
ssize_t read_min(int fd, void *buf, size_t buf_size, size_t min_to_read) {
    ssize_t total_read = 0;
    ssize_t nread;

    do {
        n_read = read(fd, buffer + total_read, buf_size - total_read);
    } while (nread > 0 && total_read < min_to_read);

    return (nread < 0) ? -1 : total_read;
}
```

Comment: Well I wouldn't need the loop since I'd have the minimum amount to start processing. I'm also not sure how to mix blocking and non blocking reads on the same FD (at least not without a bunch of syscalls).

Comment: @EricStotch, if you don't want to return until you have read at least the minimum number of bytes, then *yes*, you *do* need the loop, unless you're prepared to make assumptions about the behavior of the file you are reading, because `read()` can and does perform short reads under various normal circumstances.  And no, there is no need to mix blocking and non-blocking reads.  I don't see where you got that idea from this answer.

Comment: "because read() can and does perform short reads under various normal circumstances" How? On my system it appears files will always block (no matter what I do) and I see no linux to mix blocking and nonblocking on the same file

Comment: @EricStotch, ikegami has already described the behavior of `read()`, but perhaps different words will help: when at least one byte is requested via `read()`, it will block until it can transfer at least one byte.  At that point, it will transfer as many bytes as it can without blocking further, up to the requested maximum.  For a regular file, that generally means you get the full number requested or however many are left before the end of the file, whichever is less.  For other kinds of file (pipe, socket, ...) you can get short reads because the kernel only buffers so much data at a time.

Comment: "For a regular file, that generally means you get the full number requested or however many are left before the end of the file" <--- it looks like you're saying read will read up to the entire buffer of my file but there can be more bytes to read. Yes. I know that. I'm asking how to not full the entire buffer when it doesn't need to. It does not look like linux supports nonblocking on files anyway

Comment: Re "*I'm asking how to not full the entire buffer when it doesn't need to.*", Ask for less (provide a smaller value for `buf_size`)

Comment: @EricStotch, you seem to be inconsistent here.  The question requests to "have it fill as much as it can" (on top of which I have assumed "without unneeded blocking"), but now you seem to be saying that you instead want the bytes transferred to be limited to something less than that.  I'm not sure how much less, because I don't quite understand what you mean by "when it doesn't need to".  Certainly, if you want to cap the transfer at some amount less than the full size of the buffer, then you can do so by simply passing that cap as the (logical) buffer size.

Comment: @ikegami: Nonsense? WDYM? The documentation says "Note that this flag has no effect for regular files and block devices" and I could not get it to do a single read without blocking https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: It has no effect because it doesn't have to wait for plain files. There is always data available, or EOF was reached. In either case, it returns immediately.

Comment: @ikegami: Re “There is always data available… it returns immediately”: LOL, right, data moves instantaneously from magnetic storage to RAM, faster than the speed of light, no disk ever needs to rotate to bring the data under the head, no head ever needs to move to the right track, and no other processes ever have operations queued ahead of you.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Yes, it takes time to transfer it. But that can't be avoided, and it happens immediately. What's your point?  Note that everything you said can apply to also reading a variable from memory.

Comment: @ikegami: You wrote it does not have to wait for plain files. That is false. A process may routinely have to wait. The system could be designed to allow non-blocking I/O for this: Return immediately if no data is already present in memory for the request. The fact it does not is a software design choice, not a consequence of physical properties of files or hardware.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*That is false.*", This depends on whether you consider the disk memory or not.

Comment: @ikegami: No, it does not. When the data is not in RAM, the operating system initiates a request to get it, and the process must wait. The operating system marks the process as blocked and gives the CPU to some other process that is ready to run, if there is one, or goes to an idle state otherwise.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil,  Like I said, it depends on whether you consider disk memory or not. You apparently don't. Fine, and that makes it false *under your interpretation*, but only under your interpretation. You consider transferring to RAM and reading from memory to be two different things. But that's only two different things if you don't consider the disk memory. The system considers it memory. So much so that it can free RAM pages that are found on disk, possibly because it just put them there. Under that interpretation, the file's contents are always available.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It appears you understood what I was trying to do best. I am in fact, trying to read a bit of the file and do work while the disk is spinning

Comment: @ikegami: It does not depend on whether you consider the disk to be memory because, regardless of your consideration, the thread is in fact put into a blocked state. This is not an opinion; there is a state variable for the thread, and the operating system sets it to a value indicating the thread is blocked, and the process is not eligible for execution. It is an objective fact the thread is blocked, not a matter of consideration.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*the thread is in fact put into a blocked state. This is not an opinion*", I never said it was. You're arguing about something that was never in contention. I said data is always available and the read happens immediately. You seem to think I said something else. Everything single thing you say can be true and the read can still be immediate if those things are part of the read. You apparently don't, but that's your opinion. As it stands, the system acts as if data is always available and that the read is immediate, so my explanation stands.